# Prevent Google SupportMapFragment from reloading

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I'm having some trouble developping an Android app with a SupportMapFragment. Currently when I switch fragments, I just hide the SupportMapFragment and save the CameraPosition in SharedPreferences. Then when I show the map again, it loads the CameraPosition from the SharedPreferences. This works fine, however the map itself needs to load again. There has to be a way to save the map in a way where it barely takes any time to pop back up, like just moving it to the background or something? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: no way to stop loading a google map.

Answer (score 1):

Some screenshots proving that I have done it:

[image: Multipane mode of my app]

Multipane mode of my app

[image: Moved to singlepane and selected the map('Kort' in danish) tab]

Moved to singlepane and selected the map('Kort' in danish) tab.

What has happend is that:

1. The field variable holding map fragment is set to the singlepane map fragment, either newly created if first time seeing a map, or restored using findFragmentByTag.
   In this case it is restored using the fragment from multipane mode.
2. Because the map is restored using an existing fragment the GoogleMap instance of the map will be the same instance as we have stored in GoogleMapModule (see below), thus the state is kept.

This makes the map instantly appear, having the markers and so on as they were in multipane mode.

---

Store a reference to your map fragment as a field variable and use that whenever possible. This way you only have one map instance to worry about (re-instantiate it by using  findFragmentByTag).

Second, to store the state of the map I store the GoogleMap, which you get from calling getMap() on your map fragment, in a Activity independant of the Activity (a singleton tied to the Application lifecycle). That is, my map fragment will, whenever possible, fetch the stored GoogleMap object and use that for all operations (zoom, markers, etc..).

Here is the GoogleMapModule that I use (in case you can use some of it):

```
@Singleton
public class GoogleMapsModule extends StandardModule {

    private final GoogleMapsModulePreferences modulePreferences;

    public class GoogleMapsModulePreferences implements ModulePreferences {

        @Override public boolean isActivated() {
            return isActivated();
        }

        public int getAddressEntry() {
            return preferences
                    .getStringInt(R.string.key_googlemaps_address_entry);
        }

        public int getCityEntry() {
            return preferences.getStringInt(R.string.key_googlemaps_city_entry);
        }

    }

    public GoogleMapsModulePreferences getPreferences() {
        return modulePreferences;
    }

    public interface GoogleMapsCallback {
        public void mapReady(GoogleMap map);
    }

    public interface FetchAddressCallback {
        public void addressFound(AddressHolder addressHolder);

        public void addressLookupFailed();
    }

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleMapsModule";

    public static final int MAPTYPE_NORMAL = 0;
    public static final int MAPTYPE_SATELITE = 1;
    public static final int MAPTYPE_TERRAIN = 2;
    public static final int MAPTYPE_HYBRID = 3;

    private AddressHolder addressPin;

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private Geocoder geocoder;

    private GoogleMapsCallback googleMapsCallback;

    private final Preferences preferences;

    @Inject public GoogleMapsModule(@ForApplication Context context,
            Preferences preferences, ExpirationCoreModule expiration,
            ParseCoreModule parse) {
        super(context, preferences, expiration, parse, MODULES.GOOGLEMAPS);

        this.modulePreferences = new GoogleMapsModulePreferences();
        this.preferences = preferences;

        Log.i(TAG, "CREATING MODULE " + TAG);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, new Locale("da_DK"));
    }

    @Override public void load() {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
        loadEnded();

    }

    public void setGoogleMapsCallback(GoogleMapsCallback mapReadyCallback) {
        this.googleMapsCallback = mapReadyCallback;
    }

    public void destroyMap() {
        mGoogleMap = null;
    };

    public void clearMap() {
        clearMap(false);
    }

    public void clearMap(boolean keepAddressPin) {
        this.googleMapsCallback = null;

        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            if (keepAddressPin && addressPin != null) {
                addAddressPin(addressPin);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setMap(GoogleMap map) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            mGoogleMap = map;
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

        if (googleMapsCallback != null) {
            googleMapsCallback.mapReady(mGoogleMap);
        }
    }

    public GoogleMap getMap() {
        return mGoogleMap;
    }

    public void setMapType(int maptype) {
        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(maptype);
        }
    }

    public String mapType(int maptype) {
        switch (maptype) {
        case MAPTYPE_NORMAL:

            return "Normal";
        case MAPTYPE_SATELITE:

            return "Satelite";
        case MAPTYPE_TERRAIN:

            return "Terrain";
        case MAPTYPE_HYBRID:

            return "Hybrid";

        default:
            return "Normal";
        }
    }

    public void zoomWithBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)
            throws IllegalStateException {
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

        getMap().animateCamera(cu);

    }

    public void addLocationPin(Location location) {
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    }

    public void addAddressPin(AddressHolder addressHolder) {
        if (addressHolder.position != null) {

            String city = addressHolder.city;
            String address = addressHolder.address;

            // address or city or empty
            String title = (address != null && !address.isEmpty()) ? address
                    : ((city != null) ? city : "");

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(addressHolder.position)
                    .title(title)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

            Marker destMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            destMarker.showInfoWindow();

            addressPin = addressHolder;

        }
    }

    public void moveTo(AddressHolder addressHolder) {

        GoogleMap map = getMap();

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory
                .newLatLng(addressHolder.position);

        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
    }

    public void zoomTo(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }

        zoomTo(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    public void zoomTo(AddressHolder addressHolder) {
        if (getMap() == null || addressHolder.position == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "zoomTo map or address position was null: map "
                    + (getMap() == null) + " address position "
                    + (addressHolder.position == null));
            return;
        }

        addAddressPin(addressHolder);

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        zoomTo(addressHolder.position);

    }

    private void zoomTo(LatLng latlng) {

        GoogleMap map = getMap();

        if (getMap() == null || latlng == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 16));
    }

    public void lookupAddress(final FetchAddressCallback fetchAddressCallback,
            String address, String city) {

        new GetAddressPositionTask(fetchAddressCallback, address, city)
                .execute();
    }

    public void lookupAddress(final FetchAddressCallback fetchAddressCallback,
            String searchString) {

        new GetAddressPositionTask(fetchAddressCallback, searchString)
                .execute();
    }

    private class GetAddressPositionTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, AddressHolder> {

        private FetchAddressCallback fetchAddressPositionCallback;

        private String searchString;

        private String city = "";
        private String address = "";

        public GetAddressPositionTask(
                FetchAddressCallback fetchAddressPositionCallback,
                String address, String city) {
            this.fetchAddressPositionCallback = fetchAddressPositionCallback;

            this.city = city;
            this.address = address;
            this.searchString = address + ", " + city;
        }

        public GetAddressPositionTask(
                FetchAddressCallback fetchAddressPositionCallback,
                String searchString) {
            this.fetchAddressPositionCallback = fetchAddressPositionCallback;

            this.searchString = searchString;
        }

        @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override protected AddressHolder doInBackground(String... params) {

            final String lookupStringUriencoded = Uri.encode(searchString);

            LatLng position = null;

            try {
                if (geocoder != null) {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                            searchString, 1);
                    if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                        Address first_address = addresses.get(0);

                        String foundCity = first_address.getLocality();

                        if (foundCity != null) {
                            city = (city.isEmpty()) ? foundCity : city;
                        }

                        String addressName = first_address.getThoroughfare();
                        String streetNumber = first_address
                                .getSubThoroughfare();

                        // if (addressName != null && address.isEmpty()) {
                        address = (streetNumber != null) ? addressName + " "
                                + streetNumber : addressName;
                        // }
                        position = new LatLng(first_address.getLatitude(),
                                first_address.getLongitude());
                        Log.d(TAG, "geocoder was found " + position);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "geocoder was null, is the module loaded?");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "geocoder failed, moving on to HTTP");
            }
            // try HTTP lookup to the maps API
            if (position == null) {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                                + lookupStringUriencoded + "&sensor=true");
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    response = client.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                    int b;
                    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    // Log.d("MAPSAPI", stringBuilder.toString());

                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")
                                .getJSONObject(0);

                        JSONArray address_components = jsonObject
                                .getJSONArray("address_components");

                        String jsonCity = "";
                        String jsonAddress = "";
                        String jsonStreetNumber = "";

                        // extract looked up address information
                        for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject address_component = address_components
                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                            String type = address_component.getJSONArray(
                                    "types").getString(0);

                            String value = address_component
                                    .getString("long_name");

                            if (type.equals("locality")) {
                                jsonCity = value;
                            }

                            if (type.equals("route")) {
                                jsonAddress = value;
                            }

                            if (type.equals("street_number")) {
                                jsonStreetNumber = value;
                            }

                        }

                        Log.d("MAPSAPI", jsonCity + "," + jsonAddress + " "
                                + jsonStreetNumber);

                        city = (city.isEmpty()) ? jsonCity : city;

                        address = (address.isEmpty()) ? (jsonAddress + " " + jsonStreetNumber)
                                .trim() : address;

                        // extract position
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
                        String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
                        String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");

                        Log.d("MAPSAPI", "latlng " + lat + ", " + lng);

                        position = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat),
                                Double.valueOf(lng));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
            return new AddressHolder(address, city, position);
        }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(final AddressHolder result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GetAddressPositionTask " + result);
            if (result.position != null) {
                fetchAddressPositionCallback.addressFound(result);
            } else {
                fetchAddressPositionCallback.addressLookupFailed();
            }
            // ensure no more callbacks to this
            fetchAddressPositionCallback = null;
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

I have implemented Dagger http://square.github.io/dagger/ into my app, which explains the @Singleton, this enables me to do like this:

```
@Inject GoogleMapsModule googleMapsModule;
```

Whenever I want to use this object anywhere in my code. I think, though, that you can simply store your map data by extending Application. You could for instance read this blog: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

To keep the right reference in the GoogleMapsModule i do the following:

```
@Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    if (map != null) {
        googleMapsModule.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Now, a final loose end being if the Activity is started from scratch while GoogleMapModule holds a reference, then any operations done on the map will have no effect as the reference is not tied to a map any more. To handle this I destroy the map if savedInstanceState is null:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         // all is well
        mapsFragment = (GoogleMapFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_MAP_TAG);
    } else {
        // no saved instance - destroy the map to enable onMapReady setting a new reference
        googleMapsModule.destroyMap();
    }

    if (device.isMultiPane()) {
        addMapFragment(ft).commit();
    }
}

// called when the map tab is selected or from onCreate if multipane
private FragmentTransaction addMapFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mapsFragment == null) {
        AddressHolder address = (device.isMultiPane()) ? null
                : getSelectedAddressHolder();
        mapsFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance(address);
        ft.add(R.id.details, mapsFragment, Turios.FRAGMENT_MAP_TAG);

        mapsOptionsFragment = new GoogleMapOptionsFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.details, mapsOptionsFragment, FRAGMENT_MAP_OPTIONS_TAG);
    } else {
        ft.attach(mapsFragment);
        ft.attach(mapsOptionsFragment);
    }
    return ft;
}
```

Finally, the default behavior of Android is to start a new Activity, performing onCreate, each time the app is started, or moving back from another Activity etc.. Therefore I have set the launchMode in manifest to singleTask.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Turios"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
         >

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable_address" />
    </activity>
```

Launchmode is explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: So with this, the map doesn't have to render again? Because that doesn't really show in your screenshots

Comment: Yep, but you are right it is not directly reflected in the screenshots, have added some extra code and text.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to force the map to keep to it's data.

Comment: I found an app that actually does it a bit like the way I want to do it, it's called [Places Near Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.placesnearme). They are showing a list of locations and a map, and when you switch between the two the map doesn't need to reload